# How to keep textbox properties in two forms?

Tags: javascript, forms

I have created 2 text input fields that have a required=1 attribute in them. However, there are two forms that redirect to two pages. I have two buttons, register and log in, and they are in two forms, so that when clicked, they can redirect to the page they need to. 
However, the input fields only keep the required attribute depending on the form they are placed in. I want the input fields to always be required for both forms. I did try to place them outside of everything, but then neither of the forms make input required. Code:

```
<div class="button-container">

<form action="/login" method="get">

    <div>
        <input placeholder="Username*" class="textbox" required=1 type="text" name="username" id="username" onkeypress="return alpha(event)" maxlength="15">
        <br>
        <input placeholder="Password*" class="textbox" required=1 type="password" name="password" id="password" onkeypress="return pass(event)"> 
    </div>

    <br><br>

    <div>
        <button class="btn " type="submit" >Login</button>
    </div>
</form>

//Form 2, when i click the button, even if the boxes are empty, it redirects :(

 <form action="/finishRegister" method="post">
     <div>
        <button class="btn " >Register</button>
     </div>
</form>

<script>

function alpha(e) {
var k;
document.all ? k = e.keyCode : k = e.which;
return ((k > 64 && k < 91) || (k > 96 && k < 123) || k == 8 || (k >= 48 && k <= 57));
}
function pass(e) {
var k;
document.all ? k = e.keyCode : k = e.which;
return ((k > 0 && k < 32) || (k > 32 && k < 222));
}

</script>

</div>
```

[Here's a picture so you can see what I'm talking about. I would like, if the user presses register, to redirect to a new page to enter more account information. However, if you already have an account and press login, the username and password will suffice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dj3qF.png)

Comment: You a re misundestanding how forms work. The second form will post to "/finishRegistering", but having no inputs inside it the data will be empty.

Comment: Is there a way to make the two forms one, but maybe use onclick() for the register button to take me to /finishRegister?

Comment: I combined the two forms, and made it so onclick would do function "redirect()", and in function redirect(), I have `window.location.href = '/finishRegister'`. When i click the register button with all the fields empty, it shows the 'please fill out this field' message for a split second and then redirects to the page i want.. this is not what I want :/

Comment: @dec0mpiled why not make it a single form. If this is your real program code  you can easily achieve (what you are trying to do ) with single form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you change the action of the form dinamicly. If you inspect the console for the example below you'll see the form will try to hit "/asdf" or "/qwer" depending on the button you hit.

```js
$("input[type=submit][data-action]").click(function() {
  var
    $this = $(this),
    $form = $this.parents("form");

  $form.attr("action", $this.data("action"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Jquery Way</h1>
<form>
  <input type="submit" data-action="/asdf" value="asdf"></input>
  <input type="submit" data-action="/qwer" value="qwer"></input>
</form>

<h1> Angular Way
<div ng-app>
  <form action="{{action}}">
    <input type="submit" ng-click="action = '/asdf'" value="asdf"></input>
    <input type="submit" ng-click="action = '/qwer'" value="qwer"></input>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: are you missing a e.preventDefault()

Comment: If you `preventDefault()` you prevent form submission!